# Best way to deal with COM ports for a cross-platform program?

Tags: java, c++, cross-platform, serial-port

I am writing an application which need to send data to a serial device attached to a COM port.
I am confused as to what is the best way to deal with such a device?

Shall I write the communication module in C++ or shall I write this in Java?

I want to run the application on Windows as well as Linux.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux I would recommend [libserial](http://libserial.sourceforge.net/). You could also consider using Python. There is a multi platform [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) module. If you decide for Java, [rxtx](http://www.rxtx.org/) is a multi platform library. On Windows you may use the [Windows API for serial communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467) and combine it with libserial using `#ifndef` as @Dharma suggested.

Comment: I've used rxtx cross-platform in the past and it worked fine.

Comment: rxtx is perfect. In my case I had some trouble because I downloaded the 64 bit version since I'm on Win 7 64 bit. But since my Java installation is 32 bit I had to use the 32 bit version to get it running.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you:

[Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/asio/index.html)

[QextSerialPort](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) (based on Qt)

Answer (score 2):

You can write the module in c++ by specyfying the #ifndef "_WINDOWS_CODE" for windows code and else part for the linux code.

while compiling in Vc++ put the (_WINDOWS_CODE)macros in the projecty settings 
and in gc++ remove the macro from project file

Answer (score 1):

COM port is just a plain bit pipe. The APIs are expected to be fairly simple. In C++, the world has much more experience with writing to ports.

Other question would be - do you know what port number it is? There're several ways to find out which one is yours, like setup API on windows.

Comment: SOrry to interrupt, but i think his application is multi operating system based... C++ has big minus in this scenario!

Comment: @thatsalok: I disagree. I always made multi-operating system C++ software that uses COM ports. `C++` is perfectly suitable for that task.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, if you want to run you application in both linux and Windows, go for JAVA!. you can run your program without any need of compilation. otherwise you have to distribute seperate binary for both Windows and Linux.

Also programming model in both windows and linux for accessing SerialPort in C++, As i am preliminary a Windows C++ developer, you can use CreateFile WIn32 Api to access serial port.

Comment: Which serial comms library would you expect to work on Linux and Windows with a single binary?

Comment: I haven't about any! thats why recommended JAVA for cross plateform development.

There is something called minigw, but still you have compile your application!

Answer (score 0):

> shall i write the communication module
>   in C++ or shall i write this in JAVA?

Which are you more familiar with? Are you limited to these two languages? You could also use python with pyserial.

Are you doing this as a personal project? Is it for work? Is someone else working on this with you? What are *they* more familiar with?

For C++ you could use [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

For Java ... I don't know.